# Having problems adding '/' to end of URI

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Right now i have a url which is like

http://www.example.com/customer/login

i want the URI to always have a ending trail because ill use redirects with ../
and if it doesnt have slash it messes everything up if it has a slash it works fine. I tried to look at some examples online but i couldnt really get anything to work heres my current .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anubhava's got the basic answer and I modded him up. You need to send an HTTP redirect to get the browser to request the URL with the / at the end.

To merge with your existing rewrite rules, you should do:

```
RewriteEngine on

# First check it's not a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# And it doesn't end in /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*/$
# Send the redirect. I would do 301 (permanent) here
# the "L" means the rest of the rules are ignored for this request
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]

# Now pass thru to your old ruleset URLs the slash-checker didn't catch
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: Hmm ill have tto try this when I get home this looks promising

Comment: Only question does L mean last rule executed? Which would mean the rewrite rule at the bottom wouldn't have an effect

Comment: OK, I've tested this in Apache now and it works for me. Going to make an edit to the second inline comment but no changes to the code.

Comment: L means "don't execute any more rules after this one" ... but there's no problem, because that rule is only executed if the first two RewriteCond matches. So, for "correct" URLs with the trailing slash, they won't match the second RewriteCond and will fall thru to your original ruleset at the bottom.

Comment: What happens is: Browser requests "/foo". Matches first ruleset so server returns "HTTP 301 Location: /foo/". Browser then requests "/foo/". Which doesn't match first ruleset so second ruleset is applied, and internally rewrites request to "index.php?rt=foo/" plus original querystring params. If you don't want that last / in the rt param, then the last line would instead be: RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?rt=$1 [QSA]

Comment: i tried using example and its redirecting fine but redirecting to public_html and so on.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using following rules

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [QSA] 

#following rule checks if url is not ending with / and
#if not then redirected to url which is ending with /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  $1/ [R=302,L]
```